# ios Sqlciphier cascade delete from coredata crashed, throws 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' after deleteObject and save

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, cascading-deletes, sqlcipher

I am having an existing coredata ios 7 project. I want to encrypt my sqlLite file. While implementing sqlchipher via EncryptedStore I am facing crash when I want to delete an entity say E1 which has one to many and  relationship with other entity say E2 with delete rule cascade.

Getting log

```
 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '(null)'
```

If I delete E2 individually  then its not crashing at save context.

With out sqlcipher is working fine.

Entity Delete Rule 
[image]

code for persistence store and manage object context

```
+ (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinatorWithSqliteName: (NSString*)userFolderName fromSqliteFileName:(NSString*) fromSqliteFileNameWithOutExtension shouldCopySQLiteFromBundle:(BOOL)shouldCopyFromBundle withDataModelName:(NSString*)dataModelName
{

static NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = nil;
static dispatch_once_t tokenGRC;


    dispatch_once(&tokenGRC, ^{

        // get the model
        NSManagedObjectModel *model = [self managedObjectModelWithName:dataModelName];

        // get the coordinator
        coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];



        NSString *sqliteExtension = @"sqlite";

        NSString *sqliteFileWithExtension = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@.%@",fromSqliteFileNameWithOutExtension,sqliteExtension];


        if (shouldCopyFromBundle == YES) {

            NSError *error = nil;
            [self copySqliteFromFileName:fromSqliteFileNameWithOutExtension toUserFolder:userFolderName withError:&error];


        }
        else
        {
            NSFileManager *defaultManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

            NSArray* appDocumentDirList= [defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                                inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

            // Append the bundle ID to the URL for the
            // Application Support directory
            NSURL  *dirPath = [[appDocumentDirList objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:userFolderName];

            NSError *error = nil;
            // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
            // This method is only available in OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0 or later.

            if (![defaultManager createDirectoryAtURL:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                           attributes:nil error:&error])
            {

                NSAssert2(NO, @"%s Directory could not be created %@",__func__,[error userInfo]);
                // Handle the error.


            }

        }

        NSString *customUserDirectory = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",userFolderName,sqliteFileWithExtension];
        NSURL  *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:customUserDirectory];

        NSError *error = nil;

        //        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:databaseURL error:&error];

        NSDictionary *options = @{
                                  EncryptedStorePassphraseKey : SampleValue,
                                  //            EncryptedStoreDatabaseLocation : databaseURL,
                                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                  NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                                  };

        NSPersistentStore *store = [coordinator
                                    addPersistentStoreWithType:EncryptedStoreType
                                    configuration:nil
                                    URL:storeURL
                                    options:options
                                    error:&error];
        //        coordinator = [EncryptedStore makeStoreWithOptions:options managedObjectModel:model];

        NSAssert(store, @"Unable to add persistent store!\n%@", error);

    });



return coordinator;

}


+(A3ManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContextFromCurrentUser:(NSString*)userName withConcurrencyType:(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType)concurrencyType shouldCopySQLiteFromBundle:(BOOL)shouldCopyFromBundle withSqliteMode:(A3SqliteMode)sqliteMode
{


A3DataFetchMode dataFetchMode =  [A3WebUtility currentDataFetchMode];
NSString *fromSqliteName = nil;
NSString *toFolderName = nil;

if (dataFetchMode == A3DataFetchModeOnline) {

  fromSqliteName = @"DataBase";
  toFolderName = userName;
}
else
{
  fromSqliteName = @"DataBase-Demo";
  toFolderName = @"DemoUser";
}
NSString *dataModelName = [self dataModelNameForSqliteMode:sqliteMode];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [A3ManagedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinatorWithSqliteName:toFolderName fromSqliteFileName:fromSqliteName shouldCopySQLiteFromBundle:shouldCopyFromBundle withDataModelName:dataModelName];

if (coordinator != nil) {

  A3ManagedObjectContext *tempManagedContext = [[A3ManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:concurrencyType];
  [tempManagedContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
tempManagedContext.sqliteMode = sqliteMode;
  return tempManagedContext;
}
else
{

  return nil;
}


}
```